# online quiz using php and mysql(radio button)

Tags: php, mysql

please help, i'm developing an online quiz application. All the questions and answers will be selected from the database. Where i'm having probkem with is to get the values from the radio button whether checked or not. bellow is the code that generate the questions and answers from database.

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "<form method=post action='#'>";
    echo "<table border=0>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($display)) {
        $id = $row["id"];
        $question = $row["question"];
        $opt1 = $row["ans1"];
        $opt2 = $row["ans2"];
        $opt3 = $row["ans3"];
        $opt4 = $row["ans4"];
        $opt5 = $row["ans5"];
        $answer = $row["ans"];
        echo "<tr><td colspan=3><br><b>$question</b></td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>$opt1 <input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt1\"></td><td>$opt2     <input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt2\"></td><td>$opt3 <input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt3\"></td><td>$opt4 <input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt4\"></td><td>$opt5 <input type=radio name=q$id value=\"$opt5\">q$id</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='See how you did' name='submit'>";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

the name of the radio button is

```
<input type='radio' name='q$id' value='$opt4' />
```

How do i get the value of the checked radio button? 
or is my PHP code wrong?
what i needed is to output what is selected if a radio button is checked.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $value = $_POST[''];//the value of the radio button, i don't know what to put here
    $n = count($value);
   for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++)
   {
     echo $value[$i];
   } 
}
```

Comment: There is no code in there that checks the submited form. Only the part that outputs the form if it was NOT posted.

Comment: if edited it. where i av the problem with is how to get the value of the radio button. thanks

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't there be several different radio button names? e.g. `$_POST['q1']`, `$_POST['q2']`. It may be an idea to post these `$id` values in a hidden field so you know what names to expect.

Comment: yes the output will be 1 question 5 answers, the $id is the id of the question, q$id is the group name of the radio button, for qeustion 1, name of the radio button will be q1; for qeustion 2, name of the radio button will be q6, depending on the id of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $value = $_POST;//the value of the radio button, i don't know what to put here
    $n = count($value);
   for($i=0; $i < $n; $i++)
   {
     echo $value[$i];
   } 
}
```

$_POST[''] was wrong. You needed to use just $_POST.

You could also just use foreach here:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $values = $_POST;//the value of the radio button, i don't know what to put here

   foreach($values as $value)
   {
     echo $value;
   } 
}
```

$_POST is just a array containing whatever your form submited. If you had a name textfield you would use:

```
echo $_POST['name'];
```

to echo it.

Try

```
var_dump("<PRE>", $_POST);
```

And you will see exactly how your form is being organised. Link to [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp)

Comment: edited my answer. At this point go read some documentation we cannot explain everything to you its a lot of stuff. :) Dont forget to vote or accept answer if it helped you.

Comment: sorry, the value of the submit button is sent with the data. how do i go about this without displaying this?

Answer (score -1):

thanks for your response. i was able to come out with this code and it works but i don't know if the structure or the way i solved it is proper or good enough.

```
 <?php
 if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 echo "<form method=post action='#'>";
 echo "<table border=0>";
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($display)) {
    $id = $row["id"];
    $question = $row["question"];
    $opt1 = $row["ans1"];
    $opt2 = $row["ans2"];
    $opt3 = $row["ans3"];
    $opt4 = $row["ans4"];
    $opt5 = $row["ans5"];
    $answer = $row["ans"];
    echo "<tr><td colspan=3><br><b>$question</b></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td><input type=radio name=$id value=\"$id $opt1\">$opt1 </td><td><input type=radio name=$id value=\"$id $opt2\">$opt2 </td><td><input type=radio name=$id value=\"$id $opt3\">$opt3 </td><td><input type=radio name=$id value=\"$id $opt4\">$opt4 </td><td><input type=radio name=$id value=\"$id $opt5\">$opt5 <br>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='See how you did' name='submit'>";
echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

what i did was to include the id of the question in the value of the radio button

```
<input type=radio name=$id value=\"$id $opt1\">
```

i collect the values of the radio button using $_POST as suggested, i then explode the value into two arrays so the first array will contain the question id and the second will contain the actual value of the radio button (answer).

```
<?php
elseif (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 var_dump("<PRE>", $_POST);
 $sd = $_POST;
    foreach($sd as $sd)
    {
        $tok = explode(" ", $sd, 2);
        $w = mysql_query("select * from `questions` WHERE `id` = '$tok[0]'")or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($w) == 1)
        {
            $sf = mysql_fetch_object($w);
            echo $tok[1].".......".$sf->ans."<br>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

it works perfectly but will it give efficient result?

Comment: Got to say its kinda sad you take peoples answers to post your own without giving credit (+1, accept answer) to those who helped you. Good luck on so.

Comment: @lznogood tnx for dat comment, i would av love to do so but i don't have enough reputation to do that